# C#: Runtime Query on Linq-able data

Tags: c#, linq

This is basically a "can it be done" question.

If I have a `List<SomeObject>` is there some way to convert a user's string input into a query that can be run against the `List<>`?  The most obvious example would be having the user enter an SQL query and then running that query on the `List<>`.  I'm not necessarily interested in executing SQL, but I'm wondering if there is some way to run a linq query without hard coding it.  I don't really care what the syntax is like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). Sounds like that's what you want.